# How can i upload Default Image for all new user when the registration form is submitted

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-signals

is there anyway I can Upload Image for all new user in their profile. I created a user registration page so when a user submitted the form the new profile will be created automatically using [Django Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/signals/) the problem I'm facing now is: when a new user is created and redirected the user to home page, when a user click on the Profile page the profile page throws an error like this:

```
ValueError at /profile/15/
The 'profile_image' attribute has no file associated with it.
```

and it highlighted this html code in the page:

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="{{profile.profile_image.url}}" alt="Card image cap">
```

is there anyway I can upload image for all new user in their profile just to avoid the error message in the template. Just like How I make automatic profile for all new user.

my model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatar', blank=True, null=True)
    stories = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    twitter = models.URLField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=300,blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=200)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.user)
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

signals.py file:

```
from django.conf import settings 
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from . models import Profile

User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

#this function wake up after a User object save
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

profile template:

```
  <div class="container">
    {% for profile in profiles %}
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="{{profile.profile_image.url}}" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <a href="{% url 'edit' profile.slug %}">Edit</a>
                <a href="{{profile.website}}">My website</a>
                <a href="{{profile.twitter}}">My twitter</a> 
                <p>{{profile.city}}</p>    
                <p>{{profile.location}}</p> 
                <p>{{profile.stories}}</p>            
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

my views:

```
def profile(request, pk):
    profiles = Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    questions = Question.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    context = {
        'profiles':profiles,
        'questions':questions
    }
    return render(request, 'profile.html', context)

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        first_name = request.POST['first_name']
        last_name = request.POST['last_name']
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        password2 = request.POST['password2']

        if password == password2:
            if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                messages.info(request, 'Email or user name Already taking')
                return redirect('register')
            elif User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                messages.info(request, 'username is taken')
                return redirect('register')
            else:
                user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, first_name=first_name, 
                last_name=last_name, email=email, password=password)
                user.save();
                return redirect('login')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Password Not Match')
            return redirect('register')   
        return redirect ('/')     
    else:
        return render(request, 'signup.html')
```

Comment: simply check if user has profile image setter `src="{{profile.profile_image.url and profile.profile_image.url 
 or "PATH_TO_DEFAULT_IMAGE"}}"` Else show the default image

Comment: the New user does not have a profile image store in the **Sqlite DB** if i change the path to **{{"PATH_TO_DEFAULT_IMAGE"}}** How did the user can edit his profile page just to remove the default one created by me  ? just to add a new one of his choice

Comment: Add some logic when editing to change behavior for users that does/doesn't have an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take this approach.

Within the `media folder` you can add an image called `default.png` or `default.jpg`.

Now within your `models.py` file, you can have:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
     ...
     # setting the default image from here if none was uploaded when creating the profile
     # passing the name of the image to the default attribute
     profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatar', blank=True, null=True, default='default.jpg')
     ...
```

Also, you could do a check *(from the template)* to see if that given profile has an image:

```
{% if profile.profile_image %}
     <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ profile.profile_image.url }}" alt="Card image cap">
{% endif %}
```

I'd suggest adding both of the above to what you have though.

Answer (score 0):

Set a default in the model ImageField to a image file in a static section

```
profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatar', blank=True, null=True, default='path/to/static/default_user_image.jpg')
```

Migrating the database will add this to any empty user imagefields, and you can update it by uploading another image file with the same name. This will also prevent multiple copies of the same file.

Comment: Does user can be able to change the default Profile image in the future like using [Update View](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView)

Comment: The user can absolutely change this at a later point.  You're not changing the field, just providing the field with a built-in default value to use if one isn't provided when the profile is created.